# Prove the set of integers is not open subset of set of real number

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Please check my proof

Consider the condition of open set it must contain all of collection of intersection and union .

in this case set of integers must contain all of collection of intersection and union form real number

But it is imposible since set does not contain collection of union and intersection from irrational number,therefore it is not open set

Comment: What do you mean by "all of collection of intersection and union"?

Comment: I can't follow the proof you presented. Instead I post an answer for you to read and analyze. Just ask if you want for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us recall the following definition.

**Definition.** Let $A\subset \Bbb R$. We say that $A$ is *open* if for every $x\in A$ there exists an open interval $I$ that contains $x$ such that $I\subset A$.

Equivalently, we get

**Definition.** Let $A\subset \Bbb R$. We say that $A$ is  *not open* if there exists $x\in A$ such that for every open interval $I$ that contains $x$, we have  $I\not\subset A$.

In your question, $\Bbb Z$ is not open because there is $x\in \Bbb Z$ (in fact all $x\in \Bbb Z$) such that for every open interval $I$ that contains $x$, we have $I\not\subset \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that the original poster simply does not know what "open set" means.  I think he was trying to use the fact that a "topology" for a set (the collection of all open sets) is closed under unions and finite intersections but he seems to think that must be true of any single open set- which is not the case.